# c# linq Xdocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I call a wcf service like this:

```
XDocument xdoc = null;
xdoc = XDocument.Load("http:\\www.mydomain.com\service\helloservice");
```

I receive a xml snippet from WCF like the below:

```
<ArrayOfstring><string>hello</string><string>world</string><string>!</string></ArrayOfstring>
```

I am trying to get the content within the  elements

my code is like this but I never get anything back:

```
  var i = (from n in xdoc.Descendants("string")
                 select new { text =  n.Value});
```

when I do xdoc.DescendantNodes() I get:

```
[0] "<ArrayOfstring xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <string>HELLO</string>
</ArrayOfstring>"

[1] "<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">HELLO</string>"

[2] "Hello"
```

I am pretty new to this, I can't figure out why linq won't return results...Which Xdocument feature should I use? Some pointer would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What do you get when you call `Descendants()` with no arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Porgram
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = "<ArrayOfstring  xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><string>hello</string><string>world</string><string>!</string></ArrayOfstring>";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays";

            var text = from str in doc.Root.Elements(ns + "string")
                    select str.Value;
            foreach (string str in text)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(str);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get nothing when I do xdoc.Root.Elements("string") ?

Comment: Very Interesting. I have updated the answer to include code for a sample console program. Please make sure you have included the missing closing slash in the last string element. Please remember, if you have namespaces in the returned XML, the approach will be different. This answer is based on the XML that you included in the question.

Comment: Thanks so far. Please have a look at what I get back from the WCF service. I have updated my original post. It show what I get when I do xdoc.DescendantNodes()

Comment: I have updated the code to include the namespace support. Try this now.

Comment: thanks that worked. What is the significance of the namespace?

Comment: Namespace in xml is for avoiding name conflict. Lets say you have two xml documents with elements have same name, when you merge those two documents how do you know from which document they came from, namespace helps to solve these type of issues. Google for XM namespace and you will get a lot of resources for this.

Answer (score 0):

I did compile the code and everything seems to be fine. A little thing that you just missed was the slash charachter in your Xml document. The last string tag is not closed and it causes an exception.

```
<ArrayOfstring><string>hello</string><string>world</string><string>!</string></ArrayOfstring>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

try this, you need to cast it to expected type to get value

```
       var i = from n in xdoc.Descendants("ArrayOfstring")
                select new { text = (string)n.Element("string")};
```